# Setting up processing in scala

Tags: scala, processing

Hi I'm trying to setup processing with scala and I'm getting these errors inside def main

> overloaded method value add with alternatives: (x$1: java.awt.Component)java.awt.Component  (x$1: java.awt.PopupMenu)Unit cannot be applied to (Demoo.Starfield)

How should I do the setup if this isn't the correct way?

```
package Demoo

import processing.core._

object Starfield extends PApplet {

  private var app:Starfield = _

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    app = new Starfield
    val frame = new javax.swing.JFrame("Starfield")
    frame.getContentPane().add(app)
    app.init
    frame.pack
    frame.setVisible(true)
  }
}

class Starfield {

  override def setup() = {}

  override def draw() = {}

}
```

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

Let's process the error !

`overloaded method value add` : the error concerns the usage of an `add` method. The only candidate is `frame.getContentPane().add(app)`

`with alternatives: (x$1: java.awt.Component)java.awt.Component (x$1: java.awt.PopupMenu)Unit` : this method can be called with either a Component or a PopupMenu as parameter.

`cannot be applied to (Demoo.Starfield)` : it was called with something else, of class `Demoo.Starfield`.

Indeed, the `.add(app)` use app as a parameter, which is of `Starfield` class, so it all makes sense.

So, you need to make sure that Starfield is of one of the two accepted interfaces, for example you can modify your class this way :

```
class Starfield extends java.awt.Component {
```

Disclaimer : I know absolutely nothing about `java.awt`, so it may not be the ideal solution.